# Classes on tab key press not being added and removed correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to add a CSS class to all objects that have been tab-key navigated to.

I have the following code, it's running a function on keydown checking if the tab key has been pressed. And tries to remove the tabbed CSS class if it already exists. But only one element on my page (top element) removes the CSS for all other elements. Instead of the class being removed if it exists when someone tab navigates there.

I use this code snipped in a Gatsby site

```
 function checkTabPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {

      if(e.target.classList.contains('tabbed')) {
        e.target.classList.remove('tabbed')
      }else {
        e.target.classList.add('tabbed');
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('keydown', checkTabPress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding event listener on the document, you should add one for each element you want to have this functionality (you should have ids for the elements). Otherwise the event listener will be called each time you tab, even if you do not tab the elements you want, will check the whole document as it is now doing it.

Maybe you can do something like this.

```
function checkTabPress(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('tabbed')) {
      e.target.classList.remove('tabbed')
    }else {
      e.target.classList.add('tabbed');
    }
  }
}

var myElement = document.getElementById("my_cool_id");
myElement.addEventListener('keydown', checkTabPress);

//element 
<div id="my_cool_id"/>
```

Another option, which i forgot about is this. You can loop through the elements including the class tabbed. However, this will work if all elements by default have this class.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.tabbed').forEach(item => {
   item.addEventListener('keydown', checkTabPress)
})
```

Or you can just create a new class, for example called `tabbable`, which you will put on every element you want to have this event listener.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.tabbable').forEach(item => {
   item.addEventListener('keydown', checkTabPress)
})
```

Comment: It would be allot of work as there is a bunch of custom CSS around the site. The tab key should only be able to navigate you to tabbable events any how, so I think it is reasonable to use it this way. 

Is it not possible?